# How can I be sure that an upload with S3Client::upload() has completed successfully?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

The [AWS SDK for PHP documentation on upload()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_upload) is not very clear on how an upload succeeds, and how it fails:

```
Returns
    Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model
    Returns the modeled result of the performed operation
```

No `@throws` documented here, even though in my tests, when the request fails, a `Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException` is thrown.

Is it safe to say that:

- When it fails, I can always catch the failure with `Guzzle\Http\Exception\HttpException`
- If this exception is not thrown, then the transfer succeeded

Or:

- Are there other exceptions (in the `Aws` namespace?) that can be thrown?
- Should I look for a success indicator in the `Model` returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, no exception means success, and you can catch `Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception` for handling errors. Getting that cURL exception is odd though. Do you have any more information about that particular error?

Comment: I purposefully shut down the network interface to see what would happen if there was a network error. You can easily reproduce it this way. `S3Exception` extends `ServiceResponseException`, so it might only be thrown when an HTTP response has been received, and if the network fails, that's a Guzzle `HttpException` instead?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. The SDK does retry certain [cURL-level exceptions via the Guzzle Backoff plugin](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Plugin/Backoff/CurlBackoffStrategy.php), though. Do you happen to know what the [cURL error code was](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)? It's possible that error you had needs to be added to the plugin or the request failed multiple times and the SDK let it bubble up.

Comment: Oh definitely, it might have been tried several times, because it took a certain number of seconds before throwing the exception. Here is the exception: `Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'xxx.s3.amazonaws.com'`

Comment: I'm surprised though that instead of bubbling this exception up, Aws doesn't just wrap it into an exception of its own, setting the third parameter of `Exception::__construct()` (`Exception $previous = null`) to the GuzzleException, so that we can catch *any* error with `AwsExceptionInterface` or so, but still get the lower-level GuzzleException if needed for debugging. Maybe a suggestion to make on the issue tracker?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be a good suggestion to make on the issue tracker. :-)

Comment: I've submitted this as [issue #120](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/120), and accepting your answer in the meantime ;-)